# MySQL PROCEDURE using IF Statement with @Parameter Not Working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Why is the data not being inserted on the table when I execute the procedure, what seems to be lacking with the code?

I'm testing the procedure on phpMyAdmin > myDatabase > Procedures "Routines Tab" and clicking "Execute", prompts with a modal and ask for the values of "@idproc and @nameproc.

I tried with just the INSERT code it works, but when I add the IF condition it doesn't work.

> Using XAMPP 8.0.3,
> 10.4.18-MariaDB

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost:3307` PROCEDURE `testproc`(IN `idproc` INT, IN `nameproc` VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
IF @idproc = 0 THEN
INSERT INTO testproc(
        id,
        name)
        VALUES(
            @idproc,
            @nameproc
            );
ELSE
UPDATE testproc
    SET
        id = @idproc,
        name = @nameproc
    WHERE id = @idproc;
END IF;

SELECT * FROM testproc;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: where is your call to the sproc ? i mean you need to call the sproc with passing the data to the function, pls add that part to the question

Comment: @mahen3d i'm testing the procedure on phpMyAdmin > myDatabase > Procedures 
 "Routines Tab" and clicking "Execute" it prompts with a modal asking for the values of the two parameters "idproc", "nameproc".

Comment: @mahen3d I tried with just the INSERT code it works, but when I add the IF condition it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you edit the sproc to without the @ in front to see if that works

Comment: IF idproc = 0 THEN

Comment: @mahen3d doesn't work as well, I tried to remove the "ELSE part up to the WHERE part" to see if the problem lies on the "idproc" parameter and this is the error it gives when I input 0 on the "idproc".

- Column 'id' cannot be null

and if I input number other than 0 it executes successfully but doesn't save the data.

Is the IF condition the problem? or the "idproc" parameter not storing the input

Comment: `idproc` and `@idproc` are **two different** variables. Remove `@` char everywhere except DEFINER.

Comment: In INSERT use `VALUES (0, nameproc)`. In UPDATE remove `id = idproc,`

Comment: @Akina my mistake, I just studied the syntax and I'm still studying that is why I wanted to seek for help to clarify what I am doing wrong since the code can run but the output is not what I expected. In any case your answer is right, I would like to accept it as an answer. If you could post the answer so that I can mark it. Thank you very much for taking time to answer my question and to everyone as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix [local variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-program-variables.html) (their names have not leading `@`) and [user-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) (with single leading `@`). This is two different variable types, with different scopes and datatype rules. Procedure parameters are local variables too.

So when you use UDV which was not used previously you receive NULL as its value - and your code works incorrectly. Use LV everywhere:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost:3307` 
    PROCEDURE `testproc` (IN `idproc` INT, IN `nameproc` VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    IF idproc = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO testproc (name) VALUES (nameproc);
    ELSE
        UPDATE testproc SET name = nameproc WHERE id = idproc;
    END IF;
    SELECT * FROM testproc;
END
```

---

You do not check does specified `idproc` value exists in the table. If it is specified (not zero) but not exists then your UPDATE won't update anything. Assuming that `id` is autoincremented primary key of the table I recommend to use

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost:3307` 
    PROCEDURE `testproc` (IN `idproc` INT, IN `nameproc` VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO testproc (id, name) 
    VALUES (idproc, nameproc)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY 
    UPDATE name = VALUES(name);

    SELECT * FROM testproc;
END
```

If specified `idproc` value exists in `id` column the row will be updated, if not then the new row will be inserted.

Additionally - I recommend you to provide NULL value instead of zero when you want to insert new row with specified `nameproc` value. NULL always cause autoincremented primary key generation whereas zero needs in specific server option setting.

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed answer. I very much appreciate it.